# IntelliJ: Cannot Add Custom JavaDoc Tags

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javadoc, documentation-generation

[image]
[image]

[image]

What's the problem?

And how do I define `pre` as `Precondition` in the generated JavaDoc? For example, the supported tag `@param` is translated into

```
Parameters:
   .....
```

in the generated JavaDoc.

Comment: The error you see is reported by the javadoc tool, not by IntelliJ IDEA, therefore any IntelliJ IDEA settings are not relevant here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using a work-around:

```
/**
 * <pre>
 * "description here"
 * <b>Precondition:</b> "precondition here"
 * </pre>
 *
 * @param x  An integer.
 * other tags...
 */
```

The custom "Precondition" tag should print out in the same format as the other supported tags in the generated JavaDoc. Adjust as needed.